# Does Typescript support the ?. operator? (And, what's it called?)

Tags: typescript

Does Typescript currently (or are there plans to) support the [safe navigation](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/groovy-goodness-safe-navigation-to.html) operator of `?.`

ie:

```
var thing = foo?.bar
// same as:
var thing = (foo) ? foo.bar : null;
```

Also, is there a more common name for this operator (it's incedibly hard to google for).

Comment: @mattytommo you do have that in c#, its called the null coalescing operator and uses the ?? syntax http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx

Comment: @BasaratAli Unfortunately not, coalesce is fine for `property ?? property2`, but if you tried `property.company ?? property1.company` and `property` was null, you'd get a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @mattytommo this does exist now for C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Comment: Will be available soon. The Ecma Committee has [set priority 1 for Null Propagation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16#issuecomment-274978479) a month ago. PS it was priority 0 before (the max is 3).

Comment: The Microsoft rep that visited us called it the Elvis operator as the question mark looks like Elvis' hair and a microphone he is singing into...

Comment: The Optional Chaining is being added into TypeScript 3.7: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-beta/

Comment: It'll be part of plain JS soon - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: It was added in `v3.7` and it's called `Optional Chaining`. See my answer for code examples.

Comment: but remember that Angular (nowadays) works with typeScript `~3.1.1`

Answer (score 404, accepted):

**Yes.** As of TypeScript 3.7 (released on [November 5, 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/)), this feature is supported and is called **Optional Chaining**:

> At its core, optional chaining lets us write code where TypeScript can immediately stop running some expressions if we run into a `null` or `undefined`. The star of the show in optional chaining is the new `?.` operator for *optional property accesses*.

Refer to the [TypeScript 3.7 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) for more details.

---

Prior to version 3.7, this was not supported in TypeScript, although it was requested as early as [Issue #16 on the TypeScript repo](http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) (dating back to 2014).

As far as **what to call this operator**, there doesn't appear to be a consensus. In addition to "optional chaining" (which is also what it's called [in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html)), there are a couple of other examples:

- CoffeeScript refers to it as the [**existential operator**](https://coffeescript.org/#existential-operator) (specifically, the "accessor variant" of the existential operator):

> The accessor variant of the existential operator `?.` can be used to soak up null references in a chain of properties. Use it instead of the dot accessor `.` in cases where the base value may be **null** or **undefined**.

- C# calls this a [**null-conditional operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

> a null-conditional operator applies a member access, `?.`, or element access, `?[]`, operation to its operand only if that operand evaluates to non-null; otherwise, it returns `null`.

- Kotlin refers to it as the [**safe call operator**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

There are probably lots of other examples, too.

Comment: "accessor variant of the existential operator".  Naturally.  So catchy, it's near impossible to forget. :).  Thanks for the extremely thorough answer.

Comment: @MartyPitt Sure thing! I agree, I'd love to see a) wider adoption of an operator like this (C# please!) and b) a better name (the "safe navigation" operator from your linked blog post has a nice ring to it).

Comment: No go so far, from the issue, "The general tripwires for re-evaluating this would be a concrete ES proposal reaching the next stage, or a general consensus from the ES committee that this feature wouldn't happen for a long time"

Comment: Angular implements this in it's templates:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: In some other languages its called the "Elvis" operator

Comment: It's announced for TypeScript 3.7.0 (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16#issuecomment-515160784)

Comment: This feature is Evil. period. Shouldn't be invented.

Comment: @Appernicus I thought the elvis operator was `?:` as seen in some languages like PHP and the emerging C standard.  It's normally a shorthand ternary that wants to return itself or a default value. Instead of `x ? x : y` it would be `x ?: y`. Different from the null ops above because it's testing for "truthiness", which doesn't always involve null. Am I mislead?

Answer (score 157):

It is now possible, see [answer of user "Donut"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15260828).

Old answer:
Standard JavaScript behaviour regarding boolean operators has something that may help. The boolean methods do not return true or false when comparing objects, but in case of OR the first value that is equal to true.

Not as nice as a single ?, but it works:

```
var thing = foo && foo.bar || null;
```

You can use as many && as you like:

```
var thing = foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.check && foo.bar.check.x || null;
```

Default values are also possible:

```
var name = person && person.name || "Unknown user";
```

Comment: && evaluates as long as the statement is true. If it is true, it returns the last value. If it is false, it returns the first value that evaluated to false. That may be 0, null, false etc.
|| returns the first value that evaluates to true.

Comment: Doesn't work well if the bar is defined but evaluates to false (like boolean false, or zero).

Answer (score 121):

This is defined in the ECMAScript Optional Chaining specification, so we should probably refer to *optional chaining* when we discuss this. Likely implementation:

```
const result = a?.b?.c;
```

The long and short of this one is that the TypeScript team are waiting for the ECMAScript specification to get tightened up, so their implementation can be non-breaking in the future. If they implemented something now, it would end up needing major changes if ECMAScript redefine their specification.

See [Optional Chaining Specification](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-optional-chaining/)

Where something is never going to be standard JavaScript, the TypeScript team can implement as they see fit, but for future ECMAScript additions, they want to preserve semantics even if they give early access, as they have for so many other features.

## Short Cuts

So all of JavaScripts funky operators are available, including the type conversions such as...

```
var n: number = +myString; // convert to number
var b: bool = !!myString; // convert to bool
```

## Manual Solution

But back to the question. I have an obtuse example of how you can do a similar thing in JavaScript (and therefore TypeScript) although I'm definitely not suggesting it is a graceful as the feature you are really after.

```
(foo||{}).bar;
```

So if `foo` is `undefined` the result is `undefined` and if `foo` is defined and has a property named `bar` that has a value, the result is that value.

I put an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86sWN/).

This looks quite sketchy for longer examples.

```
var postCode = ((person||{}).address||{}).postcode;
```

## Chain Function

If you are desperate for a shorter version while the specification is still up in the air, I use this method in some cases. It evaluates the expression and returns a default if the chain can't be satisfied or ends up null/undefined (note the `!=` is important here, we *don't* want to use `!==` as we want a bit of positive juggling here).

```
function chain<T>(exp: () => T, d: T) {
    try {
        let val = exp();
        if (val != null) {
            return val;
        }
    } catch { }
    return d;
}

let obj1: { a?: { b?: string }} = {
    a: {
        b: 'c'
    }
};

// 'c'
console.log(chain(() => obj1.a.b, 'Nothing'));

obj1 = {
    a: {}
};

// 'Nothing'
console.log(chain(() => obj1.a.b, 'Nothing'));

obj1 = {};

// 'Nothing'
console.log(chain(() => obj1.a.b, 'Nothing'));

obj1 = null;

// 'Nothing'
console.log(chain(() => obj1.a.b, 'Nothing'));
```

Comment: interesting but in my case `(this.loop || {}).nativeElement` saying  `Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type '{}'. any` `this.loop` typeof https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Comment: @Kuncevic - you need to either... 1) provide a compatible default in place of `{}`, or 2) use a type assertion to silence the compiler.

Comment: Assuming `foo` is an actual useful object : `(foo || {}).bar` generally isn't going to compile in typescript because `{}` won't be of the same type as `foo`. That's the problem that @VeganHunter's solution aims to avoid.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver then (foo || {bar}).bar will let the compiler run smoothly and I think that verbosity is acceptable.

Comment: @harps actually this only compiles if bar is defined as a variable, which it wouldn't most likely be

Comment: `d` should be defined as `any`. Why is it defined as `T`?

Comment: At June 2020 the Optional Chaining operator (?.) is [supported by the most recent desktop browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Browser_compatibility), by Safari on iOS, and by Node.js. Still not yet supported on a few mobile browsers (including Firefox for Android)

Answer (score 118):

## Update: Yes its supported now!

It just got released with TypeScript 3.7 : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/

It is called *optional chaining* : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/#optional-chaining

With it the following:

```
let x = foo?.bar.baz();
```

is equivalent to:

```
let x = (foo === null || foo === undefined) ?
    undefined :
    foo.bar.baz();
```

## Old answer

There is an open feature request for this on github where you can voice your opinion / desire : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16

Answer (score 42):

## Edit Nov. 13, 2019!

As of November 5, 2019 TypeScript 3.7 has shipped and it **now supports** `?.` the optional chaining operator !!!

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

---

### For Historical Purposes Only:

**Edit:** I have updated the answer thanks to fracz comment.

TypeScript 2.0 released `!.` It's not the same as `?.`(Safe Navigator in C#)

See this answer for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875179/1057052

This will only tell the compiler that the value is not null or undefined. This will **not** check if the value is null or undefined.

[TypeScript Non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)

```
// Compiled with --strictNullChecks
function validateEntity(e?: Entity) {
    // Throw exception if e is null or invalid entity
}

function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
    validateEntity(e);
    let s = e!.name;  // Assert that e is non-null and access name
}
```

Comment: Not the same as `?` because it *asserts* that the value is defined. `?` is expected to silently fail / evaluate to false. Anyway, good to know.

Comment: Now that I think about it... This answer is pretty pointless, because it does not do the "safe navigation" that the C# operator does.

Comment: This answered my question, though. I knew about ?. from c# and tried it in typescript. It didn't work, but I saw that !. existed but didn't know what it did. I wondered if it was the same, did a google search, and found my way to this question which informed me that no, they are different.

Answer (score 19):

**The Elvis (?.) Optional Chaining Operator is supported in TypeScript 3.7.**

You can use it to check for null values: `cats?.miows` returns null if cats is null or undefined.

You can also use it for optional method calling: `cats.doMiow?.(5)` will call doMiow if it exists.

Property access is also possible: `cats?.['miows']`.

Reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-beta/

Comment: Please correct me, but the Elvis operator is at least in Kotlin `?:`. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @rekire: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-beta/

Comment: It'll be supported in plain JS soon - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Announcement of the TypeScript 3.7 release mentions it: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7/

Answer (score 16):

It's finally here!

Here are a few examples:

```
// properties
foo?.bar
foo?.bar()
foo?.bar.baz()
foo?.bar?.baz()

// indexing
foo?.[0]
foo?.['bar']

// check if a function is defined before invoking
foo?.()
foo.bar?.()
foo?.bar?.()
```

But it doesn't work exactly the same as your assumption.

Instead of evaluating

```
foo?.bar
```

to this little code snippet we are all used to writing

```
foo ? foo.bar : null
```

it actually evaluates to

```
(foo === null || foo === undefined) ?
    undefined :
    foo.bar
```

which works for all the falsey values like an empty string, 0 or false.

I just don't have an explanation as to why they don't compile it to `foo == null`

Answer (score 10):

Operator `?.` is not supported in TypeScript **version 2.0**.

So I use the following function:

```
export function o<T>(someObject: T, defaultValue: T = {} as T) : T {
    if (typeof someObject === 'undefined' || someObject === null)
        return defaultValue;
    else
        return someObject;
}
```

the usage looks like this:

```
o(o(o(test).prop1).prop2
```

plus, you can set a default value:

```
o(o(o(o(test).prop1).prop2, "none")
```

It works really well with IntelliSense in Visual Studio.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! It works in typescript 2.1.6.

Comment: or you could call it `elvis<T>` ;-)

Comment: Simon_Weaver, I call it "sad clown" :o(

Answer (score 3):

We created this util method while working on [Phonetradr](http://www.phonetradr.com) which can give you type-safe access to deep properties with Typescript:

```js
/**
 * Type-safe access of deep property of an object
 *
 * @param obj                   Object to get deep property
 * @param unsafeDataOperation   Function that returns the deep property
 * @param valueIfFail           Value to return in case if there is no such property
 */
export function getInSafe<O,T>(obj: O, unsafeDataOperation: (x: O) => T, valueIfFail?: any) : T {
    try {
        return unsafeDataOperation(obj)
    } catch (error) {
        return valueIfFail;
    }
}

//Example usage:
getInSafe(sellTicket, x => x.phoneDetails.imeiNumber, '');

//Example from above
getInSafe(foo, x => x.bar.check, null);
```

Comment: The only caveat might possibly be a performance impact, but I'm not qualified to speak to how the various JITers handle this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't generally recommend this approach (watch out for performance concerns), but you can use the spread operator to shallow clone an object, which you can then access the property on.

```
 const person = { personId: 123, firstName: 'Simon' };
 const firstName = { ...person }.firstName;
```

This works because the type of 'firstName' is 'propagated' through.

I'll use this most frequently when I have a `find(...)` expression that can return null and I need a single property from it:

```
 // this would cause an error (this ID doesn't exist)
 const people = [person];
 const firstName2 = people.find(p => p.personId == 999).firstName;

 // this works - but copies every property over so raises performance concerns
 const firstName3 = { ...people.find(p => p.personId == 999) }.firstName;
```

There may be some edge cases with the way typescript infers types and this won't compile, but this should generally work.

Answer (score 2):

It's called optional chaining and It's in [Typescript  3.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-rc/#optional-chaining)

> Optional chaining lets us write code where we can immediately stop
>   running some expressions if we run into a null or undefined

Answer (score 0):

As answered before, it's currently still being considered but it [has been dead in the water](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) for a few years by now.

Building on the existing answers, here's the most concise *manual* version I can think of:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plantface/3ghtyj8q/)

```
function val<T>(valueSupplier: () => T): T {
  try { return valueSupplier(); } catch (err) { return undefined; }
}

let obj1: { a?: { b?: string }} = { a: { b: 'c' } };
console.log(val(() => obj1.a.b)); // 'c'

obj1 = { a: {} };
console.log(val(() => obj1.a.b)); // undefined
console.log(val(() => obj1.a.b) || 'Nothing'); // 'Nothing'

obj1 = {};
console.log(val(() => obj1.a.b) || 'Nothing'); // 'Nothing'

obj1 = null;
console.log(val(() => obj1.a.b) || 'Nothing'); // 'Nothing'
```

It simply silently fails on missing property errors. It falls back to the standard syntax for determining default value, which can be omitted completely as well.

---

Although this works for simple cases, if you need more complex stuff such as calling a function and then access a property on the result, then any other errors are swallowed as well. Bad design.

In the above case, an optimized version of the other answer posted here is the better option:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/plantface/qqqayo43/)

```
function o<T>(obj?: T, def: T = {} as T): T {
    return obj || def;
}

let obj1: { a?: { b?: string }} = { a: { b: 'c' } };
console.log(o(o(o(obj1).a)).b); // 'c'

obj1 = { a: {} };
console.log(o(o(o(obj1).a)).b); // undefined
console.log(o(o(o(obj1).a)).b || 'Nothing'); // 'Nothing'

obj1 = {};
console.log(o(o(o(obj1).a)).b || 'Nothing'); // 'Nothing'

obj1 = null;
console.log(o(o(o(obj1).a)).b || 'Nothing'); // 'Nothing'
```

A more complex example:

```
o(foo(), []).map((n) => n.id)
```

---

You can also go the other way and use something like Lodash' [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#get). It is concise, but the compiler won't be able to judge the validity of the properties used:

```
console.log(_.get(obj1, 'a.b.c'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not yet (as of September, 2019), but since the "safe navigation operator" [is now at Stage 3](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16#issuecomment-515160784), it's being implemented in TypeScript.

Watch this issue for updates:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16

Several engines have early implementations:

JSC: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200199

V8: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=9553

SM: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1566143

(via https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/115#issue-475422578)

You can install a plugin to support it now:

```
npm install --save-dev ts-optchain
```

In your tsconfig.json:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "plugins": [
            { "transform": "ts-optchain/transform" },
        ]
    },
}
```

I expect this answer to be out of date in the next 6 months or so, but hopefully it will help someone in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```js
/**
 * Type-safe access of deep property of an object
 *
 * @param obj                   Object to get deep property
 * @param unsafeDataOperation   Function that returns the deep property
 * @param valueIfFail           Value to return in case if there is no such property
 */
export function getInSafe<O,T>(obj: O, unsafeDataOperation: (x: O) => T, valueIfFail?: any) : T {
    try {
        return unsafeDataOperation(obj)
    } catch (error) {
        return valueIfFail;
    }
}

//Example usage:
getInSafe(sellTicket, x => x.phoneDetails.imeiNumber, '');

//Example from above
getInSafe(foo, x => x.bar.check, null);
```

Answer (score -1):

`_.get(obj, 'address.street.name')` works great for JavaScript where you have no types. But for TypeScript *we need* the real Elvis operator!