# Dealing with Array shift return type in Typescript 2.0 with strict null checks

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In my Typescript 2.0 project with strict null checks I have an array:

`private _timers: ITimer[]`

and an if statement:

```
if(this._timers.length > 0){
  this._timers.shift().stop();
}
```

but I get a compile error:

`Object is possibly 'undefined'`

How can I convince the compiler that it's not undefined?

I can get round it like this:

```
const timer = this._timers.shift();
if(timer){
  timer.stop();
}
```

but that seems a bit too verbose and a needless use of a variable just to get round the typing constraints.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is [non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator), mentioned in 2.0 release notes (and will appear in the [documentation soon](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/pull/445/commits/6d42edac4085a78c89333bce2d6e8c3cef8929ce#diff-19c4cf88ab6db6b46bc3fc267878c3c4R363)), intended for cases exactly like this. It's postfix `!`, and it suppresses this error:

```
    if(this._timers.length > 0){
        this._timers.shift()!.stop();
    }
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350534/43848

Comment: Great, many thanks. I obviously didn't read through the release notes thoroughly enough! ☺️

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to handle a pattern I've used before to invoke and clear a list of unlisteners: `while(cleanupFns.length) { cleanupFns.shift()!(); }`

Comment: Is there a reason TS still thinks undefined is possible with shift() after checking that length of array != 0? Or, is this a bug/issue with TS.

Comment: @TylerAuer i wonder the same. Seems like a bug since we already check for existing items

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that `_timers` has been initialized?
For example:

```
private _timers: ITimer[] = [];
```

Or in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this._timers = [];
    ...
}
```