# typescript - object is possibly 'null'

Tags: angular, typescript

I get this error for the following but the program running perfectly

[image: error]

```
var video = document.querySelector('#camera-stream'),

if(!navigator.getMedia){
        displayErrorMessage("Your browser doesn't have support for the navigator.getUserMedia interface.");
    }
    else{
        // Request the camera.
        navigator.getMedia(
            {
                video: true
            },
            // Success Callback
            function(stream:any){

                // Create an object URL for the video stream and
                // set it as src of our HTLM video element.
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

                // Play the video element to start the stream.
                video.play();
                video.onplay = function() {
                    showVideo();
                };

            },
            // Error Callback
            function(err:any){
                displayErrorMessage("There was an error with accessing the camera stream: " + err.name, err);
            }
        );

    }
```

[image: example error]

I tried the solution [in this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-typescript-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefine) but didn't work for me.

What is the proper fix for this error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try casting:

```
var video = document.querySelector('#camera-stream')
```

to:

```
var video = <HTMLVideoElement>document.querySelector('#camera-stream')
```

Answer (score 37):

TypeScript has a special syntax for handling this scenario, the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).

When you *know* the value is actually neither `null` nor `undefined` but the compiler does not, you can use the non-null assertion operator, `!`, to communicate this. This works on an expression by expression basis.

```
declare let video: HTMLVideoElement | null | undefined;

video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); // error

video!.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); // OK

video.autoplay = true; // error as the `!` does not percolate forward

video!.autoplay = true; // OK
```

However, it is far more likely that we do not  definitively know that the object in question is neither `null` nor `undefined` and, after all, that possibility is what the type was deliberately written to convey. In such a case, using the `!` syntax would suppress a compile time error but could result in a runtime failure. In this case we should rather handle the possibility by ensuring that the object is truthy before dereferencing it. A common idiom for writing this code is

```
if (video) {
  video.member
}
```

In fact, TypeScript uses a contextual type checking technique known as [control flow based type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) and thereby determines that `video` can safely be dereferenced in the `if` statement block because the `null` and `undefined` types have be removed from the union by truthy check. Therefore, the above code does not result in any errors because TypeScript knows that it is safe.

It is best to use the `!` syntax very sparingly.

Comment: The same can be done with the new optional chaining operator (?.)

Comment: That's true, but it wasn't sure at the time I wrote the answer.

Comment: Yeah..That had not been standardized those days. just wanted to let the future readers know :-)

Answer (score 13):

Simon's answer can also be written using `as` (preferred by some linters like airbnb):

```
var video = document.querySelector('#camera-stream') as HTMLVideoElement;
```

Answer (score 5):

Generally, if you want to disable the strict **null checks function** in TypeScript, you can use the character `!` where the error is shown, as below:

```
this.myRef.current!.value = ''
```

Note: do this if you're sure about the object

Comment: How is this answer different from the most-upvoted answer that was written two years before this one? -1