# TypeScript 2: Import statement generates TS2532: "Object is possibly 'undefined'."

Tags: javascript, typescript, commonjs, typescript2.0

I have a TypeScript 2 file in which I'm attempting to make use of an image like this:

```
import image = require("../assets/images/image.jpg");
```

However, this throws

```
[at-loader] ./src/components/app.tsx:3:30 
    TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

What is the recommended way to make use of an asset without the risk of it being undefined? Note that I don't want to suppress the warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress TypeScript "error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-typescript-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefine)

Comment: @KukicVladimir Thanks! But I don't want to suppress it. Checking for possibly undefined variables is useful. It feels like there should be a way to import an asset without throwing this error.

Answer (score -1):

> import image = require("../assets/images/image.jpg");

You cannot `import` an image file like this.

You probably wanted to do `img` with a `src` set to the image tag.

## More

There are indeed ways to import an image file with webpack bundling e.g. using raw file loader, but I doubt that is what you are doing here.