# How to fix Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code.

```js
const body = /<body.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/.exec(html)[1];
```

It compiles with the error below.

> Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check for a match first, before accessing the match results. This regex will cause issues if the text you match does not contain `</body>` tag and the text is large enough, BTW. And it will never match `<body>` tag that contains line breaks in between attributes. That is why regex is not a good idea when parsing HTML.

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-typescript-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefine

Comment: Thanks @PieroAlberto

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I am able to solve this question using non-null assertion operator `!` as below

```
const body = /<body.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/.exec(html)![1];
```

Comment: Also possible to use optional chaining as well.


`const body = /<body.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/.exec(html)![1];`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the `!` operator, one other option could be to use the optional operator `?` and use a default value.

```
const body = /<body.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/.exec(html)?[1] ?? '';
```