# TypeScript undefined coercing

Tags: typescript, undefined, type-coercion

I was writing a Redux reducer when I found that this code:

```
export function users(state: { myself: IUser | undefined, users: IUser[] } = { myself: undefined, users: [] }, action: UserActions) {
  const mself = state.myself;
  if (action.type === EMyselfAction.CHANGE_MYSELF_CONFIG && state.myself !== undefined) {
    return {
      myself: myself(mself, action),
      users: state.users.map((u) => user(u, action, state.myself.id)),
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

Is outputting the error Object is possibly 'undefined':

[image]

How can be `state.myself` undefined if it is already checked that it is not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to suppress TypeScript "error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-typescript-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefine)

Comment: Could you please post the error message as text instead of only posting it as a screenshot? That might help others facing the same errors finding a question via google.

Comment: TS won't always "change" the type of a parameter due to assertion (`T is` type guards or `!== null` checks). You might have better luck replacing `state.myself` with `mself` and asserting against that (local variable change more readily).

Comment: @k0pernikus I know how to suppress that error. The problem is that there is a condition which is forcing the `if` body only to be executed if state.myself is not undefined.

Comment: @ssube That is one solution but, why is the compiler not asserting the type? It is obvious IMO that state.myself is not undefined due to the assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's because `state.myself` is in a different scope.

```
export function users(state: { myself: IUser | undefined, users: IUser[] } = { myself: undefined, users: [] }, action: UserActions) {
  const mself = state.myself;
  if (action.type === EMyselfAction.CHANGE_MYSELF_CONFIG && state.myself !== undefined) {
    state.myself // (property) myself: IUser

    const foo = () => {
       state.myself // but here is (property) myself: IUser | undefined
    }
    // ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I don't think you can guarantee otherwise, since you can use it somewhere else (not only in that branch where `state.myself !== undefined`). So you could do this:

```
export function users(state: { myself: IUser | undefined, users: IUser[] } = { myself: undefined, users: [] }, action: UserActions) {
  const mself = state.myself;
  if (action.type === EMyselfAction.CHANGE_MYSELF_CONFIG && state.myself !== undefined) {
    const id = state.myself.id;
    return {
      myself: myself(mself, action),
      users: state.users.map((u) => user(u, action, id)),
    };
  }
  ...
}
```