# Angular 2 getBoundingClientRect() object is possibly 'Null'

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, getelementbyid

So, how to get some element offset by ID in Angular 2?

Done this:

```js
scrollToBottom () {
 let content = document.getElementById('content')
 let offsetTop = content.getBoundingClientRect().top
 console.log(content, offsetTop)
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Object is possibly 'null'
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-typescript-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefine#40350534

Answer (score 0):

Cause there can be no element with this id in html. Just check in if statement;

```
scrollToBottom () {
let content = document.getElementById('content')
if (content) {
   let offsetTop = content.getBoundingClientRect() ? content.getBoundingClientRect().top : 0
   console.log(content, offsetTop)
 }

}
```

Comment: wait, there is element with this id, it's not an dynamic one?

Comment: also this is not helping at all :(

Comment: doesn't matter document.getElementById('content') can return null