# Object is possibly 'undefined' - after filter that contains check for undefined

Tags: typescript

I'm doing an operation on an array like this:

```
.filter(key => actions && actions[key])
.forEach(key => actions[key](event, dispatch));
```

But I'm getting a TypeScript error on the `forEach` `actions`: `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

Yet it can't be `'undefined'` as it is filtered for those entries that *do* have `actions`.

Comment: It's always possible this is a bug or short-falling of the current typescript language

Comment: @Andreas the TS error was specifically on `actions`, not `actions[key]`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think the TypeScript compiler is smart enough to realize the `filter` method has already removed all `undefined` entries from the array.  In this case, you can help the compiler out by telling it that `actions[key]` is defined by using the non-null assertion operator `!` as described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350534/1063392

```
.filter(key => actions && actions[key])
.forEach(key => actions![key](event, dispatch));
```

Comment: This remains a problem though if the non-null assertion operator is forbidden by the lint rules in the project.