# Typescript error Object is possibly null? Why, how to disable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
private extractInitials(fullname: string): string {
    const initials = fullname
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, '')
        .match(/\b\w/g)
        .join('')
        .toUpperCase();
    return initials.substring(0, 2);
}
```

I'm getting an error
[image]

`[ts] Object is possibly 'null'. [2531]`

So I tried 
`if fullname { const initials .... return ... } else return '';`

Turns out typescript was complaining about this guy

`fullname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, '')`

Which makes sense because this might end up being an empty string

So I did

```
const t = fullname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, '')
if(t) { /* do the rest */ } else return ''
```

and it still gave me the object is possibly null error. I know it's not. How do I fix?

Comment: It's the *match* that might be null, hence that's where the underlining is.

Comment: *"Which makes sense because this might end up being an empty string"* No, that doesn't make sense. `""` is not `null`. They're quite different things.

Comment: You can use a non-null assertion on the match result if you're confident the source string will be non-empty: `.match(/\b\w/g)!` -- if the text is empty you will get `null` from that and `.join()` will throw an error.

Answer (score 11):

The issue is that `match` can return `null`. If you want a blank string as as result, just use the `||` trick¹ to do `|| []` on the result of `match`:

```
private extractInitials(fullname: string): string {
    const initials =
        (fullname
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, '')
        .match(/\b\w/g)
        || []
        )
        .join('')
        .toUpperCase();
    return initials.substring(0, 2);
}
```

If you want to return `null` in that case instead, you can use the `&&` trick¹ to return the `null` if the `match` result is `null`, otherwise continuing on with your `join` etc.:

```
private extractInitials(fullname: string): string {
    const parts = fullname
        .replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, '')
        .match(/\b\w/g);
    return parts && parts.join('').toUpperCase().substring(0, 2);
}
```

---

¹ The `||` trick is that `||` evaluates its left-hand operand and, if it's *truthy*², takes that value as its result; otherwise it evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result. The `&&` trick is similar, just the other way around: It evaluates its left-hand operand, and if it's *falsy*³, takes that value as its result; otherwise, it evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that value as its result.

² *falsy* - `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, `NaN`, or (of course) `false`

³ *truthy* - not falsy

Answer (score 4):

I run into a similar issue, in my case, all I did was to add the following rule to the tsconfig.json

```
"strictNullChecks": false
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

That should do the work

Comment: Thanks for this. Easiest solution so far :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to remove the null check error could be to use [Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining).

```
const extractInitials = (fullname: string): string  => {
    const initials = fullname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, '').match(/\b\w/g)?.join('').toUpperCase();
    return initials?.substring(0, 2) || '';
}
```

This will return an empty string if the result of regex match is `null`, otherwise will return the expected output.
You can try running it with different values in the TS playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgKYA84CcCGY4EkoCWcBmANjAgLwIAUAZgK6mlSYC2SAXAvOgVAHMAlN178BCKgD4EAb1CTJkWIn5ES5KgkbNWHBYoB06JAAdS2JDQD0AbQB6mALQAvAIJOAWk4QBdawIANAgA5CFChmyYcGAAFjYAOgBGCQDuAUIA-IYAVhD8NGERcBAAqqamSOgAwpgwVkIA3AaSJnAM6FAIasRkMNkwDEligjQADMEATEIIAD6zoSHNIAC+oKDKMBCkSIakEAKFJoOkqjDcIcGoGNh4hL3kheFNQA).

This has been explained in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58121244/895666) as well.