# typescript: object is possible undefined, but i use if chained to check

Tags: typescript

I have this code,
but i get an error on this code underlined 'startups[i].logo' is possible undefined, why this error if I use if to check the values ?

```
  for (let i = 0; i < startups.length; i++) {
    let startup = startups[i];
    if (startups[i] && startups[i].logo && startups[i].logo.location) {
      aStartup.push({
        objectID: startups[i].id,
        logo: startups[i].logo.location,
      });
      batchCount ++;
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `startups`?

Comment: At which stage of the transpilation does the error happens?

Comment: startups comes from a select , i've updated the question

Comment: webstorm alert show the error, and when webstomr show error then the compile will give error too

Comment: Then i think you'll find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-typescript-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefine) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the nullable parts to local variables:

```
for (let i = 0; i < startups.length; i++) {
  const startup = startups[i];
  const logo = startup.logo;

  if (startup && logo && logo.location) {
    aStartup.push({
      objectID: startup.id,
      logo: logo.location
    });

    batchCount ++;
  }
}
```

This makes a difference because TypeScript knows all nullable scenarios have been eliminated within this block.