# Object is possibly 'null'. TS2531 Error when defining useScroll hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-hooks

I have the following component definition:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

export default function useScroll() {
    const ref = useRef(null)
    const executeScroll = () => {
        if (ref != null)
            window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop)
    }
    const htmlElementAttributes = { ref }

    return [executeScroll, htmlElementAttributes]
}
```

The line `window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop)` throws the error. I have included `if (ref != null)` check, but did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: `ref.current` is null

Answer (score 1):

Try `ref.current !== null`, because:

```js
const ref = useRef(null); // ref is object { current: null }
ref !== null;             // always true
```

```js
import { useRef } from 'react';

export default function useScroll() {
    const ref = useRef(null)
    const executeScroll = () => {
        if (ref.current !== null)
            window.scrollTo(0, ref.current.offsetTop)
    }
    const htmlElementAttributes = { ref }

    return [executeScroll, htmlElementAttributes]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, still the same error persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-typescript-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefine