# How to work around Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531) error in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, null, isnull

I have seen [How to suppress "error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefined). And other things. This is **not a duplicate!**

There are like 3 different ways to *suppress* this error. I do not want what.  I do not want to disable strict null types either. I want a proper solution to code this properly.

Can I create a new type that is the same as `HTMLElement` and `Element` just without null? What will happen at run-time if they are actually null and I just suppress the warning in TS. It feels like a horrible workaround.

```
function insertAfter( newNode: HTMLElement, referenceNode: Element ) : void {

    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore( newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling );
}
```

This is not working. TS linter is not smart enough to detect this:

```
function insertAfter( newNode: HTMLElement, referenceNode: Element ) : void {

    if ( null === referenceNode ) {
        throw Error( 'ref node is null');
    }

    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore( newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling );
}
```

Found this here: https://rules.sonarsource.com/typescript/RSPEC-2966 also not working.

```
function insertAfter( newNode: HTMLElement, referenceNode: Element ) : void {
    if ( referenceNode ) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore( newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling );
    }

    throw Error( 'ref node is null');
}
```

I am new to TypeScript but this is the most annoying thing. I hope there is a solution that I just did not find yet.

Comment: "*This is not working. TS linter is not smart enough to detect this:*" it **is**. It's not complaining about `referenceNode` but `referenceNode.parentNode` which might be `null`. Check the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMBnApgJygQWFLACkTHQHcA5OAE3QC5EAJAFQFkAZAUQBt0BbdGCgAaRJnTAsgiOiq0GPfoKiIAlIgYA3ODGqIA3gChDiU8mCJiYEN26IAvI7ESpkWTXRqDJs76gALTDgyRE5MIMxiAHJxCzAPZFQSG24o1QBuH1MAX2NfWNcZOXQAOgAHAENxIWKSlAxsACEJOHErcmLRAuqijxLSAA8oAGUYACNuFABzNUzsoA) and take a good note of the message and where it comes from.

Comment: Yeah, `null === referenceNode.parentNode` is the test you should do.  You know `referenceNode` isn't `null` because `insertAfter` doesn't accept a `null` value for `referenceNode`.  But `parentNode` might be `null`.

Comment: You are right its about the Parent node. I am using VScode and its actually underlining both and showing both errors in many cases. If I put code that makes no sense in it it sometimes is only underlines the thing after a dot with "does not exist of type never". So seems a bug in the linter.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually about `.parentNode` as the guys in the comment pointed out. But VScode is buggy about this, it shows both errors.

[image]

This solution works:

```
function insertAfter( newNode: HTMLElement, refNode: Element ) : void {

    if ( null === refNode.parentNode ) {
        throw Error( 'refNode.parentNode is null');
    }

    refNode.parentNode.insertBefore( newNode, refNode.nextSibling );
}
```