# How do I solve 'Object possibly null' error in TS?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draftjs

I have similar problem to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529845/how-to-work-around-object-is-possibly-null-ts2531-error-in-typescript), using Draft.js wiht React and Typescript.
Using the same code as their docs' example, I get `Object is possibly 'null'` error in the `focusEditor` function. It persist even when I check for null reference (just like the solution in the SO question I quoted above). Here's the code with added null checks:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Editor, EditorState } from 'draft-js';

export default () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

  const editor = React.useRef(null);

  function focusEditor() {
    if (null === editor) {
      throw Error('editor is null') 
    }
    if (null === editor.current) {
      throw Error('editor.current is null') 
    }
    editor.current.focus(); // Error: Object is possibly 'null'
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    focusEditor()
  }, []);

  return (
    <div onClick={focusEditor}>
      <Editor
        ref={editor}
        editorState={editorState}
        onChange={editorState => setEditorState(editorState)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This should be enough to reproduce the error, I have the `@types/draft-js` installed as well, no other issues.

Comment: Have you tryed `editor?.current?.focus(); `

Comment: `editor?.current?.focus();` this yields 2 other errors: `Parsing Error: expression expected` and `property focus does not exist on type 'never'`

Comment: try editor && editor.current && editor.current.focus()

Comment: This is because you are checking the editor and editor.current to be null where as editor.current.focus can also be null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `editor` is implicitly set to `React.MutableRefObject<null>` which is an object with a `current` property that holds the generic argument passed in. So the signature will be similar to this:

```js
interface MutableRefObject<T> {
  current: T | null
}
```

Since you pass in `null`, the generic argument is inferred to also be `null`. Therefore, that is the only value that `editor.current` should be able to hold.

You should explicitly tell the TypeScript compiler what you expect to have as the generic argument by passing it as `useRef<SomeType>()`. You could sidestep the issue by using `any` as the generic argument at the price of some type safety but you are better off saying what exactly would that object's type would be. Here is an example:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface Focusable {
  focus: () => void
}

const editor = React.useRef<Focusable>(null);

function focusEditor() {
  if (null === editor) {
    throw Error('editor is null') 
  }
  if (null === editor.current) {
    throw Error('editor.current is null') 
  }
  editor.current.focus(); 
}
```

[See on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgDEI0BXAZxQCMAbZgG9ycOJnbcAXHAAUASjgBeAHxwAbhGAATcgF9KaCNS7wk24DGjLExGADpuSZJgA8bTjwFIVs6h35+eQpyTA5qDGBjcUkuAFELKygFOBExYEw5f0DlJSU4c0toRTSxOBgACxwAdzg4qBxk-EKkuGAuOGz+fEVROAN0zL8A-lz8luh7TgakWhK+sUqauoboWWbEyemiWjaOrp64PoGCzagpjhnaewlPBVIjvSA)

I'm not sure what is the expected type to go there, it might be better to just use `HTMLElement` or even something more specific like `HTMLTextAreaElement` instead of the `Focusable` I created as an example.

At any rate, this can be improved:

`React.useRef()` always returns *an object* and `editor` is a constant, thus it cannot be reassigned. This means that it will never be `null`. You can remove the first check.

The only thing that could be `null` is `editor.current`. If you don't want to throw an error, you can simply do a standard null guard which will satisfy the type checking:

```js
if (null !== editor.current) {
  editor.current.focus();
}
```

This can be further shortened using the [nullish coalescing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) so you end up with this:

```js
import React from 'react';

const editor = React.useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

function focusEditor() {
  editor.current?.focus();
}
```

[See on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4kATYGaOAXkWJgDoBXOkmSYAPAAkAKgFkAMgFEANkhBIaMAHwAKGv0WKAlBXKZ+NDMFpxMENIPks2ULQbgBvcnDjNW0XnagidQB+Xhs7OhcKAF8gA)

Comment: `HTMLInputElement` may be a better alternative