# TypeScript error TS2532, Object is possible undefined

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I installed WebStorm 2020.1 yesterday.

Suddenly I got a bunch of TS2532 errors.

[image]

How can this be "possible undefined"? The `selectedOwner &&` protects against that?

I tried to disabled this stupid error with `"strictNullChecks": false,` but has no effect.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: This question is very clear, very specific, and on topic. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @wentjun No, added ts-ignores. Very annoying.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue on 2021.2

Answer (score 1):

Webstorm is occasionally slow to propagate the changes.

What I would recommend is to check and ensure that you the webstorm TypeSript service is using the right TypeScript version, and that it is using the right `tsconfig.json` file on your project.

On the Webstorm menu, go to **Preferences** -> **Languages & Frameworks** -> **TypeScript**.

Ensure that is is loading TypeScript from your project's `node_modules`, and not anywhere else. In addition, the compile scope should be set to `Project Files`

It may also help if you restart TypeScript service.

In addition, if you are using TypeScript 3.7.5 and above, you can simplify your conditional rendering by using optional chaining:

```
selectedLocalOwner?.id && .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You say

> I tried to disabled this stupid error with "strictNullChecks": false, but has no effect.

Where did you put this check?
I have put it in my tsconfig.json as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48401853/2528609
and it works just fine.