# React Testing Library Cleanup is not un-mounting the component tree

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-testing-library

I am learning to use TypeScript with a ToDo app. I have added redux to it and now testing the application.

I am using `cleaup()` provided by [React-Testing-Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#cleanup), which seems to be called, but my tests fail because the previous tests data is visible in the next test.

```js
it('adds a todo when a user clicks on the "ADD" button', () => {
    render(<App />);
    const todo: string = "first task";
    userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("textbox"), todo);
    expect(screen.getByRole("textbox")).toHaveValue(todo);

    userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));
    expect(screen.getByRole("textbox")).toBeEmptyDOMElement();
  });

  it("lists down all the todos", () => {
    const { container } = render(<App />);
    const todos: string[] = ["todo 1", "todo 2", "todo 3"];
    todos.forEach((todo: string) => {
      userEvent.type(screen.getByRole("textbox"), todo);
      expect(screen.getByRole("textbox")).toHaveValue(todo);
      userEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button"));
      expect(screen.getByRole("textbox")).toBeEmptyDOMElement();
    });
    let querySelector = container.querySelector("#all-todos");
    expect(querySelector).not.toBeNull();

    // Use of ! => https://stackoverflow.com/a/63084260/379235
    expect(querySelector!.childNodes.length).toBe(todos.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < querySelector!.childNodes.length; i++) {
      expect(querySelector!.childNodes.item(i).textContent).toBe(todos[i]);
    }
  });
```

How can I prove that? Just reverse the order of these tests and all tests pass.

I am not sure what is a better way to unmount the rendered tree, than calling the `cleanup()` method.

I have a codesandbox link which reproduces this issue. You can find this at https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-library-cleanup-issue-57tdy

Can someone help me understand how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

To avoid, render fresh component each time or in a beforeEach:

```js
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ToDoApp />
      </Provider>
    );
```