# Prevent "Object is possibly 'undefined'." using this.el in Stencil.js components

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

Stencil won't compile my components since the latest updates. The problem is the following:

```
@Element() el: HTMLSpxEditElement
@Listen('keydown', { target: this.el })
  onClickEnter (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
      evt.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

Getting this error:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.

L49:      @Listen('keydown', { target: this.el })
L50:      onClickEnter (evt) {
```

I read through this thread here: [How to suppress "error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefined) but changing "this.el" to "this!.el" is not helping either.

I don't want to change settings of the compiler.

Comment: If you know for sure `this.el` can never be null or undefined then just cast it to the appropriate type `{ target: (this.el as TypeIKnowItToBe) }`. Otherwise you'll have to check for null/undefined to satisfy the compiler. Read *all* of the answers on that question, there are plenty of ways to skin this particular cat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress "error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the event listener didn't need to be specified, as it already applied to the host element.

```
@Listen('keydown')
  onClickEnter (evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
      evt.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

This fixed my issue.