# Typescript: Object is possibly 'undefined' but only for '<' and '>' operators

Tags: typescript

I've been having a really strange `Object is possibly 'undefined'` error. My goal is an condition like this:

`if (productPages?.length && productPages[productPages.length - 1].docs?.length < 10){...}`

But the condition `productPages[productPages.length - 1].docs?.length < 10` leads me the error `Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

The thing is If I change the `<` operator for another one like `==` or `===` the error disappears, which, to me, seems odd.

I don't want to use the `! - Non-null assertion operator`, but I can't find any other solution for it.

Typescript versions tested: 3.7.3 and 4.0.5.

Comment: Nothing odd about that. Checking if something is equal to `undefined` makes sense. Checking if it's greater or less than it doesn't.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefined

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole left side will evaluate to `undefined` if the optional chaining falls through. In such a case, your code is like:

```
if (undefined < 10)
```

Which doesn't make sense, so TypeScript raises the error.

Using `===` isn't a problem because checking to see if a value is `===` to `undefined` is *not* nonsensical.

If the `docs` will definitely exist, then remove the optional chain from it: `.docs.length`. But since you don't know whether the `productPages[productPages.length - 1]` exists, you'll need an optional chain for it as well. (Your `?.` might be in the wrong place.)

If you don't know if the `docs` will exist or not, you'll need to figure out the logic you want: do you want to run the code if the nested array isn't found, or do you want to run the code only if the nested array is found? Change to something like:

```
const length =  productPages[productPages.length - 1]?.docs?.length;
if (length !== undefined && length < 10) {
// or
// if (length === undefined || length < 10) {
```

depending on the logic you want.

Comment: The part in the comment should be `||`, I would assume?

Comment: Oops, yep, definitely.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it.

Comment: `undefined < 10` actually _makes sense_: it's `false` in JS, and this can be really useful.