# typescript TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' in two-way binding angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do a two-way binding between a 'user' variable and a form in the html template :

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User = {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
    age: 0,
    adress: {
      street: '',
      city: '',
      state: ''
    }
  };
  ...
```

example from the form: (I don't want to paste a lot of code)

```
 ...
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="street">Street Adress</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="user.adress.street"
          name="street"
        />
 </div>
 ...
```

when I bind user.firstname, user.lastname or user.age it works:
example :

```
          [(ngModel)]="user.age" //works
```

but when I try user.adress.street, user.adress.city, or user.adress.state id does not compile
example :

```
          [(ngModel)]="user.adress.street" //does not work
```

but when I go to the interface User and I click save: the compilation works

```
export interface User{

    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    age?: number;

    adress?: {
        street?: string,
        city?: string,
        state?: string
    }

    active?: boolean;
    registered?: any;
    hide?: boolean;
}
```

and when I edit the ts or the html file and I save: it gives me a compilation error :

```
Failed to compile.

src/app/components/users/users.component.html:39:36 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

39           [(ngModel)]="user.adress.street"
                                      ~~~~~~

  src/app/components/users/users.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './users.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UsersComponent.
```

I tried using

```
user?.adress?.street
```

but it didn't work

Comment: What behavior do you expect if you provide a non-existing property ?

Comment: you may check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefined

Comment: In your TS code, the potential *null* values are protected with **optional chaining**, but not your HTML code. Try using `[(ngModel)]="user?.adress?.street"`

Comment: Try this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67203677/10025862

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I fixed it, with a turnaround :

instead of using user.adress.street

I created a variable ' adress ' in the component

and in the template I used adress.street

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to check the content of object using *ngIf="user.adress.street", in this case, angular will wait for this object to be filled.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="street">Street Adress</label>
  <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          *ngIf="user.adress.street"
          [(ngModel)]="user.adress.street"
          name="street"
        />
</div>
```

If your object has many fields, it could be hard to do it in all objects on HTML. I this case you could create a div with *ngIf and put the content inside.

```
<div *ngIf="user.adress.street"> 
    ...
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="street">Street Adress</label>
      <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              [(ngModel)]="user.adress.street"
              name="street"
            />
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Angular binding mostly works on predefined types (string, number, any) or types that we are declaring explicitly such as interface. Now in code mentioned above class level variable is not declared properly either it must be a type of "any" or any interface. Please use the link mentioned below for verification.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6u1v6q?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score -1):

In your component.ts:

```
  user = new User("", "", 0, {
    street: "Test",
    city: "",
    state: ""
  });
```

---

After that create a class like this one:

```
export class User {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  age?: number;

  adress: {
    street?: string;
    city?: string;
    state?: string;
  };

  active?: boolean;
  registered?: any;
  hide?: boolean;
  constructor(firstname, lastname, age, adress) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.age = age;
    this.adress = adress;
  }
}
```

---

At the end your Html template should be:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="street">Street Adress</label>
  <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          [(ngModel)]="user.adress.street"
          name="street"
        />
</div>
```

---

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgtch5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)