# Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a `Type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'. I am trying to validate an email address onkeyup event in angular.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mynform',
  templateUrl: './mynform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mynform.component.css']
})
export class MynformComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    function EmailValidation(): void {
      var email: string = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("txtEmail")).value;
      var error: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("error");
      error.innerHTML = "";
      var expr: RegExp = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

      if (!expr.test(email)) {
        error.innerHTML = "Enter valid email address format";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="email" class="notify" autocomplete="off" id="txtEmail" 
onkeyup="EmailValidation();" />
      <span id="error"></span>
```

Comment: Well, the error is correct; you have something that could be `null`, but you're treating it as if it can't be `null`. What is the question?

Comment: what should i do to solve the null error problem ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress "error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefined)

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementById(id)` may return `null`. If you can guarantee that the element with id "error" exists then you should be able to fix it by adding a `!` after: `var error: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("error")!`.

Alternatively, change the type of the `error` variable to allow `null`: `var error: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("error")`