# In Angular, on making an observable, error "Object is possibly null" appears, but it is not null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, formgroups

I have two projects, and in one, this code yields no error:

```
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    s: new FormControl('')
  })

  fo$ = this.form.get('s').valueChanges.pipe(
    map(a => console.log('something'))
  );
```

But in my new project, this brings up the error `"Object is possibly 'null'."` How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349987/how-to-suppress-error-ts2533-object-is-possibly-null-or-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

It's probably the case where you have `strict` mode enabled in one project, and disabled in other project.

#### Solution

Go to the `tsconfig.json` file and disable `strict` mode in the project where it's enabled.

Comment: WHen I do the import { UntypedFormGroup, UntypedFormControl } from '@angular/forms';
I am getting error. These untypedformgroup and ubntypedformcontrol don't exist on my system. How to add (or install) them?

Comment: Is your project created with Angular 14?

Comment: Angular is 13. Node is 14.

Comment: Ok then... `UntypedFormGroup` and `UntypedFormControl` are introduced in Angular 14. Can you check `tsconfig.json` file and check if `strict` mode is enabled in one project, but disabled on other?

Comment: changing the strict to false solved the problem.

Comment: Nice! I updated my answer with that info as a solution.