# Cypress - nested function instead of using while loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I spotted that when I'm using while loop, cypress does not work, so instead of while loop I found this kind of solution:

```js
const functionName = () => {
  if ( a != b ) {
    this.functionName();
  } else {
    cy.get(".selector").click()
  }
};
```

This block of code (typescript) works really well, but 'this' is highlighted in red and the message appears: "Object is possibly 'undefined'."

Any idea how can I to get rid off this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's a typescript error, add the [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

```
// Compiled with --strictNullChecks
function validateEntity(e?: Entity) {
  // Throw exception if e is null or invalid entity
}
function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
  validateEntity(e);
  let s = e!.name; // Assert that e is non-null and access name
}
```

For reference, [How to suppress "error TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350534/16997707) answers the same question.

You probably don't need the `this.` prefix at all, since the function is defined on the current scope (not a class method).