# Best way to assure TypeScript that this.props.data is non-null with Apollo?

Tags: typescript, apollo

I check this.props.data.loading, and if it's done (and no error) then I'd like to directly use this.props.data.  However, TS tells me that it may be null b/c of the way Apollo types are implemented.

What's the best way to avoid needing to write something like this every time?

```
(this.props.data as any).myData.foobar
```

For example, I can throw if it's null (which it should never be).  But this is an annoying solution because if I have many places that render differently based on whether data is loaded, then this code would be all over the place.

```
if (!this.props.data) { throw new Error("Data is null!"); }
```

Fairly new to Apollo and I think this is a fairly basic question.

Answer (score 1):

The **non-null assertion operator** `!` looks like it will do exactly what I want.

```
this.props.data!.myData.foobar
```

[Documented in TypeScript 2.0.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)

(Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350534/152711) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875179/152711) SO answers.)