# const a: any = someValue !;

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular-changedetection

I studied the source code of the mechanism `changeDetaction` in angular6 and came across an interesting design that neither I nor the guys from work know, The code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6b79ab5abec8b5a4b43d563ce65f032990b3e3bc/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L154), does anyone know what it is or how it works? Specifically, line 60:

```
let changes: SimpleChanges = undefined !;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the history of the file (e.g. [blame view](https://github.com/angular/angular/blame/6b79ab5abec8b5a4b43d563ce65f032990b3e3bc/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L160)), you will find out how this line came [into existence](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/8c4b96392740be60c0d174e064506cc06aa5dc0f):

> fix(core): Update types for TypeScript nullability support (#15472)

You will find the the *non-null assertion operator*  in the [TypeScript design notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7395) which introduces

> A new `!` postfix expression-level operator.

It tells the compiler, that the value (and property) cannot be null. See also these related stackoverflow questions and answers:

- [! operator in typescript after object method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38875179/112968)
- [What does the exclemetion mark after the function mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48619969/112968)