# How do I create a file for a Visual Studio Code Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a file as a part of one of the commands in my extension and can't seem to get it right.

```ts
let wsedit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
const file_path = vscode.Uri.file(value + '/' + value + '.md');
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(file_path.toString());
wsedit.createFile(file_path, {ignoreIfExists: true});
vscode.workspace.applyEdit(wsedit);
vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Created a new file: ' value + '/' + value + '.md);
```

`value` is a string input from the user.  The code executes, but from what I can tell no file is being created.  How do I properly create the file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like the [`vscode.Uri`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#Uri) does not support relative paths ([here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34449) is the corresponding issue). With that said you have to use an absolute path. The following snippet should work (tested on windows with vscode v1.30.0)

```ts
const wsedit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
const wsPath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath; // gets the path of the first workspace folder
const filePath = vscode.Uri.file(wsPath + '/hello/world.md');
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(filePath.toString());
wsedit.createFile(filePath, { ignoreIfExists: true });
vscode.workspace.applyEdit(wsedit);
vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Created a new file: hello/world.md');
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for your first line there that states "Object is possibly 'undefined'".  Any thoughts?

Comment: on `const wsedit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();`? Maybe you can just add my line two and three into your snippet and give it a try. (Btw. I used typescript)

Comment: I was able to accomplish it by using a form of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874928/operator-in-typescript-after-object-method).  After getting the object I then check to make sure that it's not undefined.