# How do I copy files from within a VSCode extension to the workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have certain files within the VSCode extension `src` folder that I would like to copy into the root of the workspace on running a certain command. Once this is working I would also like to extend this to copy other static files with specific content into other sub-folders within the workspace. I found a way to create new files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073926/how-do-i-create-a-file-for-a-visual-studio-code-extension). However, I am unable to find a way to copy entire files bundled within the extension into the workspace. Looking at the MSFT documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/overview), I cannot find anything that would work for my use case. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: create the file and read the extension file content with `workspace.fs` and edit/write this to the new file, there is an API function that fives you the path of the extension (If my memory is correct)

Comment: Can you confirm if this is how you created the extension? I am stuck in a similar issue and wondering what's the best way to copy files is.

Comment: Yes, I used a simply copy command mapped to an action.

Answer (score 1):

I created a function `copyFile` that can copy file from within a VSCode extension to the workspace at the provided destination.

You can use [WorkspaceEdit](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceEdit) and [FileSystem](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystem) VS Code API to achieve this task as shown below.

```js
async function copyFile(
  vscode,
  context,
  outputChannel,
  sourcePath,
  destPath,
  callBack
) {
  try {
    const wsedit = new vscode.WorkspaceEdit();
    const wsPath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath;
    const data = await vscode.workspace.fs.readFile(
      vscode.Uri.file(context.asAbsolutePath(sourcePath))
    );
    const filePath = vscode.Uri.file(wsPath + destPath);
    wsedit.createFile(filePath, { ignoreIfExists: true });
    await vscode.workspace.fs.writeFile(filePath, data);
    let isDone = await vscode.workspace.applyEdit(wsedit);
    if(isDone) {
      outputChannel.appendLine(`File created successfully: ${destPath}`);
      callBack(null, true);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    outputChannel.appendLine(`ERROR: ${err}`);
    callBack(err, false);
  }
}
```

Sample function call:

```js
function activate(context) {
  ...
  let testChannel = vscode.window.createOutputChannel("TestChannel");
  // copy tasks.json file from vs code extension to the destination workspace
  copyFile(vscode, context, testChannel, 
           'assets/tasks.json', '/.vscode/tasks.json', function(err, res) {});
  ...
}
```