# What does ! mean in the context of react refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-data-grid, react-ref

I was looking through the react-data-grid source code and noticed this line: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/34a2e51931bba2ac8a2f738cd059945d66516b48/packages/react-data-grid/src/HeaderCell.tsx#L107

```
    return x - this.cell.current!.getBoundingClientRect().left;
```

I can't seem to figure out what the ! is doing.

Comment: [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [! operator in typescript after object method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874928/operator-in-typescript-after-object-method)

Answer (score 1):

That means that you are sure that variable value `this.cell.current` is not undefined or null