# How to circumvent TypeScript typechecking when I know more than it

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class Blog {
    private _id?: number

    private async create() {
        const id = await getIdOfBlog()
        this._id = id
    }

    async track() {
        await this.create()
        doSomethingWithId(this._id)
    }
}

function doSomethingWithId(id: number) {
    
}
```

TS will complain:

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I understand why it happens. TS thinks `this._id` could be undefined, although I know more, I have context that `this.create()` will fill the variable. Is it possible to circuvein the type checking without using `@ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 2):

`_id` is marked as optional, TS warns about this and it is right. The code logic is probably flawed and you attempt to fool TS instead of fixing the logic.

If `_id` must be optional then either `doSomethingWithId()` should allow `undefined` as argument or `track()` must call `doSomethingWithId()` only if it is sure that `_id` is set.

On the other hand, `_id` is an identifier and an identifier is never `undefined`. It represents the identity of the object; it cannot be `undefined` and it must be set when the object is created.

Your class does not have a constructor and this makes its instances just regular objects with a fancy prototype. The purpose of a class is to enforce the creation and usage of entities that are always consistent. The code `const x = new Blog()` produces an empty object. It's `_id` property is `undefined` (`_id` is not even present in `x`).

This is how it can be implemented using OOP at its full potential and not just as a buzzword:

```js
class Blog {
    public constructor(private id: number) { }

    async track() {
        doSomethingWithId(this.id)
    }
}
```

And this is how it is used:

```js
const id = await getIdOfBlog()
const x = new Blog(id)
```

Now `x` is a valid object. It has a value in its identity property.

This approach has other advantages too. I guess `getIdOfBlog()` gets the value from a database or another external resources. In the tests of class `Blog` you don't want to wait for the code that accesses external resources; you don't even want to run such code in tests.
In the tests of class `Blog` you can simply create an instance of the class as `new Blog(42)` then use it.

Comment: Excellent answer.  This is definitely a case of an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

I usually handle this by adding a test that throws an error:

```
async track() {
    await this.create()
    if (!this._id) throw new Error("Blog does not have an id")
    doSomethingWithId(this._id)
}
```

This way typescript knows that if the control flow is on the last line, then `this._id` must have a truthy value.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQJIBMDywBCANnMgBQCUiA3ogFCKIBO6IjSACo3ALYwDOqAHTM+cQgDdUpAIwAmAMzlaAX1q0IhAIZ8+iIiWr0GiAA6MY4zVFSIA+jCwB+AFyIwIbgCNUjNcdPmltaI2gCekIgQzFZSlFRG-gwQCHxQiA6IALwhAO6aMGlomLgExGRKicZQABb8gvZYWelYCYiqrWERUIyaEADWFIaVDJp5BYg1dVGoMRSt-jDAiKQAhJN89Q6UNVw5bqh7AKKMXIykAET6yIhYcKi6YHBp1ZqSIUgO5xXDtwDKPOhamBkAB1ArVbCkdabLDfBiqdqgSCwBA3OD-biAmDAsE1SEOVzuLw+OKtFRAA)

---

Additionally, you can use [the `!` postfix operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874928/operator-in-typescript-after-object-method), which means:

> *"I, the programmer, am asserting that this nullable type is actually guaranteed not to be `null` or `undefined` in this scope."*

```
async track() {
    await this.create()
    doSomethingWithId(this._id!)
}
```

Usually though, this is discouraged in all but the absolute simplest of cases. If you are wrong (or there is a bug elsewhere) you'll get some strange error messages in other functions that will be harder to track down.

So if you opt for this method, and for some reason it actually is `undefined`, then you probably throw an error either way, but this way the error message will be far less helpful.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQJIBMDywBCANnMgBQCUiA3ogFCKIBO6IjSACo3ALYwDOqAHTM+cQgDdUpAIwAmAMzlaAX1q0IhAIZ8+iIiWr0GiAA6MY4zVFSIA+jCwB+AFyIwIbgCNUjNcdPmltaI2gCekIgQzFZSlFRG-gwQCHxQiA6IALwhAO6aMGlomLgExGRKicZQABb8gvZYWelYCYiqrWERUIyaEADWFIaVDJp5BYg1dVGoMRSt-lhwAMo86LVgyADqBdXYpJN89Q4AhBXGqu2gkLAIiIsr3GswG9s1ew6u7l4+ca0qQA)