# What does `undefined!` means in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint

typescript source code use `undefined!` in many places. For example, in [binder.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/binder.ts), from line 261 to 271:

```
            file = undefined!;
            options = undefined!;
            languageVersion = undefined!;
            parent = undefined!;
            container = undefined!;
            thisParentContainer = undefined!;
            blockScopeContainer = undefined!;
            lastContainer = undefined!;
            delayedTypeAliases = undefined!;
            seenThisKeyword = false;
            currentFlow = undefined!;
```

From typescript official docs, the postfix `!` means "Non-null assertion operator", and it's definition is that:

> A new ! post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact

So this usage `undefined!` seems make no sense, because it asserts that undefined is non-undefined.

What is the meaning of `undefined!`, and why we use in that way ?

Comment: Probably "this will never be null in runtime"...

Comment: @user202729 it sounds reasonable, but I have never known this usage, hope more details or docs

Comment: Possibly relevant answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874928/operator-in-typescript-after-object-method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So this usage undefined! seems make no sense, because it asserts that undefined is non-undefined.

> What is the meaning of undefined!, and why we use in that way ?

Another way to put it is, telling typescript "Shut up, I know what I'm doing". If `strictNullChecks` is on, Typescript will complain when assigning `undefined`/`null` to a value with a type that doesn't include `undefined`/`null`.

`strictNullChecks` is a good default, but there are cases where you might want to assign `undefined` or `null` anyway (maybe in a local scope or private part of a library), and you yourself guarantee that you're always going ensure a value is set *later*.

The benefit is that the user of the library doesn't have to deal with optional properties, and you, as the library author, might have a bit more flexibility about how objects are built before they leave the boundary of your library.

Example:

```js
type MyArticle = {
  title: string;
}

function getArticle(): MyArticle {

  const result:MyArticle = {
    // ignore the undefined error, we're dealing with this later.
    title: undefined!,
  };

  result.title = 'Hello world';
  return result;

}
```

The above example is contrived. There's better ways to structure it, and I suspect that that's true for the sample you shared as well.