# Angular 11- Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently, I am working on user registration in Angular.
Here is my part of code where I'm trying to compare Password and ConfirmPassword:

```
comparePasswords(fb: FormGroup) {
let confirmPswrdCtrl = fb.get('ConfirmPassword');

if (confirmPswrdCtrl.errors == null || 'passwordMismatch' in confirmPswrdCtrl.errors) {
  if (fb.get('Password').value != confirmPswrdCtrl.value)
    confirmPswrdCtrl.setErrors({ passwordMismatch: true });
  else
    confirmPswrdCtrl.setErrors(null);
 }
}
```

The problem is that Angular warns me about **confirmPswrdCtrl**, that it can be possibly null:

> error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

What's wrong and how can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `confirmPswrdCtrl?.errors`

Answer (score 3):

you need to let typescript know it's there. simplest way is as so:

```
let confirmPswrdCtrl = fb.get('ConfirmPassword') as FormControl;
```

Comment: Is good, but now it says that   fb.get('Password')   is possibly null...

Comment: well you could do the same thing like `let passwordCtrl = fb.get('password') as FormControl` or just assert not null like `if (fb.get('Password')!.value != confirmPswrdCtrl.value)`

Comment: Thank you bryan60 ! You're the best!

Comment: @bryan60 side question, you are using `fb.get('Password')!.value` but I have never seen `!` used like this before. could you explain it real quick or share a link

Comment: never mind, I found a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874928/operator-in-typescript-after-object-method)

Comment: yea, non null assertion operator

Answer (score 0):

Open tsconfig.json and add "strictNullChecks": false to angularCompilerOptions

```js
{
  ...
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    ...
  }
}
```