# What is the meaning of !. operator, used in object property assingment?

Tags: typescript

It was written as `data.attrs!.type = this.type`.
I found this operator on the https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VBtn/VBtn.ts page

Comment: It's call non-null assertion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874928/operator-in-typescript-after-object-method

Comment: Don’t tag typescript questions as javascript unless it actually applies to both languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [! operator in typescript after object method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874928/operator-in-typescript-after-object-method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Comment: There is no `!.` operator; you should parse it like `(data.attrs!).type = this.type`.