# The FormGroup component requires implementation

Tags: angular

I don't know if it's the Angular update, but I notice that it asks to initialize variables, like: A "String" asks to put "", a number to put "0"... But what about when it's a "**FormGroup component**"? How do I resolve this?

```
public productForm : FormGroup ; This returns me an error.
```

I saw that there is an option that puts a "!" at the end of the variable, like this:

public productForm! : FormGroup ;

What's it for?

Comment: `!` is referred to as **Non-null assertion operator** used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact. Answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38874928/9471852) question may give you more clarity.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand about the exclamation. Then I did some research and solved the issue using this:

```
this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
    'name': new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
      forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
    ]),
    'alterEgo': new FormControl(this.hero.alterEgo),
    'power': new FormControl(this.hero.power, Validators.required)
  });
```