# What are the meanings of ! signs (exclamation) in type definitions in .tsx files?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

What are the meanings of ! signs in type definitions in *.tsx files?

Is it sugar coat of a feature while creating an a instance property?

For example: `provider!: Web3Provider;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874928/operator-in-typescript-after-object-method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Comment: I think question should stay. It is not duplicate of any other non-null assertion operator info. I already knew what is it but I just discovered it is available in `instance properties `

Comment: This is not just a simple `non-null assertion operator` It's special for assignments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments.

I found answer by ...

1. removed ! sign from code.
2. TSlint said: `Property 'provider' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)`
3. The Quick fix tool recommended me to add **Definite Assignment Assertions**
4. Googled *Definite Assignment Assertions*  and found out they are That's the non-null assertion operator.

It is a way to tell the compiler "don't complain about the possibility of it being null or undefined."

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions