# What's the best way to check for multiple nulls? For example if(foo.bar.giz.mo.x === 123)

Tags: javascript

I remember hearing about a new way of doing this in ECMAScript 5 or 6 or 7 that lets you do something like:

```
if(SomeOperator foo.bar.giz.mo.x === 123)
```

Does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: You're asking how to check if a chain of properties is defined, without throwing errors if any of the keys don't exist? I don't think there's anything new for that?

Comment: I can't find them, but there should be plenty of duplicates. The idiom is `if (foo && foo.bar && foo.bar.giz && foo.bar.giz.mo && foo.bar.giz.mo.x == 123)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Typescript support the ?. operator? (And, what's it called?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260732/does-typescript-support-the-operator-and-whats-it-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: It's called the null propagating operator `?.` and it does just what you need.

Bad news: It exists in C# 6.0 and Typescript, but no sign of it coming to ES6-7, even if proposals for it are many.

Shortest way to achieve this in JS is unfortunately still

```
if(foo||{}.bar||{}.giz||{}.mo||{}.x === 123)
```

Comment: You mean `foo&&foo.bar&&foo.giz...` etc

Comment: With the help of ellipsis and shorter-than-usual variable names sure :P `person||{}.address||{}.street||{}.number` vs `person && person.address && person.address.street && person.address.street.number`

Comment: The code in the answer would throw a `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`.

Comment: I think the answer is trying for [this answer to Does Typescript support the ?. operator? (And, what's it called?)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15264573/215552), but missed the parentheses.

Comment: Assuming the base variable is never declared they would both throw exceptions.

Comment: 'even if proposals are many' can't find on tc39/proposals. Link?