# Safe navigation operator (?.) or (!.) and null property paths

Tags: typescript

In Angular 2 templates safe operator `?.` works, but not in `component.ts` using TypeScript 2.0. Also, safe navigation operator (`!.`) doesn't work.

For example:

This TypeScript

```
if (a!.b!.c) { }
```

compiles to this JavaScript

```
if (a.b.c) { }
```

But when I run it, I get the follow error:

> Cannot read property 'b' of undefined

Is there any alternative to the following?

```
if (a && a.b && a.b.c) { }
```

Comment: The typescript operators only exist for compilation, they are not present in the compiled javascript. The error you posted is a runtime error.

Comment: o(o(o(o(test).level1).level2).level3 or o(o(o(o(a).b).c).d https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169378/3914072 this solution works great for us at compilation time and it's with safe types

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Typescript support the ?. operator? (And, what's it called?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260732/does-typescript-support-the-operator-and-whats-it-called)

Comment: this is such a difficult thing to Google.  Thank you!

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Since TypeScript 3.7 was released you can use optional chaining now.

**Property example:**

```
let x = foo?.bar.baz();
```

This is equvalent to:

```
let x = (foo === null || foo === undefined)
  ? undefined
  : foo.bar.baz();
```

Moreover you can call:

**Optional Call**

```
function(otherFn: (par: string) => void) {
   otherFn?.("some value");
}
```

`otherFn` will be called only if `otherFn` won't be equal to `null` or `undefined`

**Usage optional chaining in IF statement**

This:

```
if (someObj && someObj.someProperty) {
  // ...
}
```

can be replaced now with this

```
if (someObj?.someProperty) {
  // ...
}
```

Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html

Comment: this keeps throwing **Expression expected** error when compiling, it works if I use `!` instead of `?` in "typescript": "~3.5.3"

Comment: @Scaramouche this is because the optional chaining operator (`?.`) was introduced in 3.7 and you're running 3.5.3. In versions earlier than 3.7, TypeScript assumes that `?` is being used in the shorthand if form (`foo ? bar : baz`) and so expects the rest of the expression

Answer (score 244):

`!` is [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (post-fix expression) - it just saying to type checker that **you're** sure that `a` is not `null` or `undefined`.

> the operation `a!` produces a value of the type of `a` with `null` and `undefined` excluded

---

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) finally [made](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33294) it to typescript (**3.7**)

> The optional chaining operator `?.` permits reading the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid. The `?.` operator functions similarly to the `.` chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`. When used with function calls, it returns `undefined` if the given function does not exist.

**Syntax**:

```
obj?.prop // Accessing object's property
obj?.[expr] // Optional chaining with expressions
arr?.[index] // Array item access with optional chaining
func?.(args) // Optional chaining with function calls
```

**Pay attention**:

> Optional chaining is not valid on the left-hand side of an assignment

```
const object = {};
object?.property = 1; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Comment: For those interested in checking in on the status of this.  TypeScript is planning on adding it once ECMAScript adds support.  ECMAScript is tracking this issue [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

Comment: o(o(o(o(test).level1).level2).level3 or o(o(o(o(a).b).c).d https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169378/3914072 this solution works great for us at compilation time and it's with safe types

Comment: playground of the new feature (will release on November 5): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.0-pr-33294-11#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRycAJqVBOugPwBcR2yBxryCwYAng+mFKADmLNkQAOAez4BhCaQi9+QkUQC+BdfgLyEAGziV2EkH2QBXTFAYZoBAhegA6MhSq1HHbkA

Comment: @aleksey-l: It might not be a bad idea to strikethrough the stuffs prior to the "last update".   It will help people who don't read top to bottom (i.e. too fast)! :)

Comment: This is so cool - I had no idea that you could use it for function calls. Was looking for a solution and came across your answer, so thank you!

Answer (score 23):

**Update:**

Planned in the scope of 3.7 release
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33352

---

You can try to write a custom function like that.

The main advantage of the approach is a type-checking and partial intellisense.

```
export function nullSafe<T, 
    K0 extends keyof T, 
    K1 extends keyof T[K0],
    K2 extends keyof T[K0][K1],
    K3 extends keyof T[K0][K1][K2],
    K4 extends keyof T[K0][K1][K2][K3],
    K5 extends keyof T[K0][K1][K2][K3][K4]>
    (obj: T, k0: K0, k1?: K1, k2?: K2, k3?: K3, k4?: K4, k5?: K5) {
    let result: any = obj;

    const keysCount = arguments.length - 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= keysCount; i++) {
        if (result === null || result === undefined) return result;
        result = result[arguments[i]];
    }

    return result;
}
```

And usage (supports up to 5 parameters and can be extended):

```
nullSafe(a, 'b', 'c');
```

Example on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20nullSafe%3CT%2C%20%0D%0A%09K0%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%20%0D%0A%09K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK0%5D%2C%0D%0A%09K2%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK0%5D%5BK1%5D%2C%0D%0A%09K3%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK0%5D%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%2C%0D%0A%09K4%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK0%5D%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%2C%0D%0A%09K5%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK0%5D%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%5BK4%5D%3E%0D%0A%09(obj%3A%20T%2C%20k0%3A%20K0%2C%20k1%3F%3A%20K1%2C%20k2%3F%3A%20K2%2C%20k3%3F%3A%20K3%2C%20k4%3F%3A%20K4%2C%20k5%3F%3A%20K5)%20%7B%0D%0A%09let%20result%3A%20any%20%3D%20obj%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09const%20keysCount%20%3D%20arguments.length%20-%201%3B%0D%0A%09for%20(var%20i%20%3D%201%3B%20i%20%3C%3D%20keysCount%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09if%20(result%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%7C%7C%20result%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%09%09result%20%3D%20result%5Barguments%5Bi%5D%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09return%20result%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20B%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20C%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%09d%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%3A%20A%20%3D%20null%3B%20%0D%0Aconsole.log(nullSafe(a%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(nullSafe(a%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(nullSafe(a%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.b.c%20%3D%20new%20C()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(nullSafe(a%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.b.c.d%20%3D%20%7B%20e%3A%20'ee'%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(nullSafe(a%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'))%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AnullSafe(a%2C%20'c')%3B%20%2F%2F%20compile%20error%0D%0AnullSafe(a%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'%2C%20'f')%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%20because%20of%20any).

Comment: This works nice, but It has a problem - VSCode will not show this when using "Find All References" on one of the keys.

Comment: What kind of type checking ? The moment you pass strings in as params, you have lost the type. If so, you are better off to just use lodash.get

Answer (score 17):

Another alternative that uses an external library is [_.has()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has) from [Lodash](https://lodash.com).

E.g.

```
_.has(a, 'b.c')
```

is equal to

```
(a && a.b && a.b.c)
```

EDIT:
As noted in the comments, you lose out on Typescript's type inference when using this method. 
E.g. Assuming that one's objects are properly typed, one would get a compilation error with (a && a.b && a.b.z) if z is not defined as a field of object b. But using _.has(a, 'b.z'), one would not get that error.

Comment: Nice tip, while no other solution is available, this seems to be a good alternative.

Comment: But how does it work with TypeScript's type inference?

Comment: @VitalyB probably u mean importing corresponding interface of lodash. 
(import * as _ from 'lodash';)

Comment: @AnkurArora, I think what VitalyB means is that no type checking is done using the Lodash method. E.g. Assuming that one's objects are properly typed,  one would get a compilation error with (a && a.b && a.b.z) if z is not defined as a field of object b. But using _.has(a, 'b.z'), one would not get that error. As for the import statement, yes, it is definitely needed.

Comment: @TiaanM That's exactly what I meant. I just found a new library, however, that covers the types issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55462483/126574

Answer (score 4):

A new library called **[ts-optchain](https://github.com/rimeto/ts-optchain)** provides this functionality, and unlike lodash' solution, it also keeps your types safe, here is a sample of how it is used (taken from the readme):

```
import { oc } from 'ts-optchain';

interface I {
  a?: string;
  b?: {
    d?: string;
  };
  c?: Array<{
    u?: {
      v?: number;
    };
  }>;
  e?: {
    f?: string;
    g?: () => string;
  };
}

const x: I = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: {
    d: 'world',
  },
  c: [{ u: { v: -100 } }, { u: { v: 200 } }, {}, { u: { v: -300 } }],
};

// Here are a few examples of deep object traversal using (a) optional chaining vs
// (b) logic expressions. Each of the following pairs are equivalent in
// result. Note how the benefits of optional chaining accrue with
// the depth and complexity of the traversal.

oc(x).a(); // 'hello'
x.a;

oc(x).b.d(); // 'world'
x.b && x.b.d;

oc(x).c[0].u.v(); // -100
x.c && x.c[0] && x.c[0].u && x.c[0].u.v;

oc(x).c[100].u.v(); // undefined
x.c && x.c[100] && x.c[100].u && x.c[100].u.v;

oc(x).c[100].u.v(1234); // 1234
(x.c && x.c[100] && x.c[100].u && x.c[100].u.v) || 1234;

oc(x).e.f(); // undefined
x.e && x.e.f;

oc(x).e.f('optional default value'); // 'optional default value'
(x.e && x.e.f) || 'optional default value';

// NOTE: working with function value types can be risky. Additional run-time
// checks to verify that object types are functions before invocation are advised!
oc(x).e.g(() => 'Yo Yo')(); // 'Yo Yo'
((x.e && x.e.g) || (() => 'Yo Yo'))();
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Pvl's answer, you can include type safety on your returned value as well if you use overrides:

```
function dig<
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T
  >(obj: T, key1: K1): T[K1];

function dig<
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T[K1]
  >(obj: T, key1: K1, key2: K2): T[K1][K2];

function dig<
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T[K1],
  K3 extends keyof T[K1][K2]
  >(obj: T, key1: K1, key2: K2, key3: K3): T[K1][K2][K3];

function dig<
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T[K1],
  K3 extends keyof T[K1][K2],
  K4 extends keyof T[K1][K2][K3]
  >(obj: T, key1: K1, key2: K2, key3: K3, key4: K4): T[K1][K2][K3][K4];

function dig<
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T[K1],
  K3 extends keyof T[K1][K2],
  K4 extends keyof T[K1][K2][K3],
  K5 extends keyof T[K1][K2][K3][K4]
  >(obj: T, key1: K1, key2: K2, key3: K3, key4: K4, key5: K5): T[K1][K2][K3][K4][K5];

function dig<
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T[K1],
  K3 extends keyof T[K1][K2],
  K4 extends keyof T[K1][K2][K3],
  K5 extends keyof T[K1][K2][K3][K4]
  >(obj: T, key1: K1, key2?: K2, key3?: K3, key4?: K4, key5?: K5):
  T[K1] |
  T[K1][K2] |
  T[K1][K2][K3] |
  T[K1][K2][K3][K4] |
  T[K1][K2][K3][K4][K5] {
    let value: any = obj && obj[key1];

    if (key2) {
      value = value && value[key2];
    }

    if (key3) {
      value = value && value[key3];
    }

    if (key4) {
      value = value && value[key4];
    }

    if (key5) {
      value = value && value[key5];
    }

    return value;
}
```

Example on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20dig%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%0D%0A%20%20%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key1%3A%20K1)%3A%20T%5BK1%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20dig%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K2%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%0D%0A%20%20%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key1%3A%20K1%2C%20key2%3A%20K2)%3A%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20dig%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K2%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K3%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%0D%0A%20%20%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key1%3A%20K1%2C%20key2%3A%20K2%2C%20key3%3A%20K3)%3A%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20dig%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K2%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K3%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K4%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%0D%0A%20%20%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key1%3A%20K1%2C%20key2%3A%20K2%2C%20key3%3A%20K3%2C%20key4%3A%20K4)%3A%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%5BK4%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20dig%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K2%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K3%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K4%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K5%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%5BK4%5D%0D%0A%20%20%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key1%3A%20K1%2C%20key2%3A%20K2%2C%20key3%3A%20K3%2C%20key4%3A%20K4%2C%20key5%3A%20K5)%3A%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%5BK4%5D%5BK5%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20dig%3C%0D%0A%20%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K1%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20K2%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K3%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K4%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20K5%20extends%20keyof%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%5BK4%5D%0D%0A%20%20%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key1%3A%20K1%2C%20key2%3F%3A%20K2%2C%20key3%3F%3A%20K3%2C%20key4%3F%3A%20K4%2C%20key5%3F%3A%20K5)%3A%0D%0A%20%20T%5BK1%5D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%5BK4%5D%20%7C%0D%0A%20%20T%5BK1%5D%5BK2%5D%5BK3%5D%5BK4%5D%5BK5%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20value%3A%20any%20%3D%20obj%20%26%26%20obj%5Bkey1%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(key2)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%20%3D%20value%20%26%26%20value%5Bkey2%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(key3)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%20%3D%20value%20%26%26%20value%5Bkey3%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(key4)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%20%3D%20value%20%26%26%20value%5Bkey4%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(key5)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%20%3D%20value%20%26%26%20value%5Bkey5%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20value%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20A%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20B%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%09c%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test%3A%20Test%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09b%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%09%7D%2C%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20dig(test%2C%20'a')%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20dig(test%2C%20'a'%2C%20'b')%3B%0D%0A).

Answer (score 0):

Versions above typescript 3.7 supports safe navigation operator for typescript < 3.7 I made this function which can be useful.

```
export function isAccessible(data, keys, start=0) {
  if (start == 0 && (data == null || data == undefined)) {
    console.warn("data",data);
    return false;
  } else {
    if (data[keys[start]] == null || data[keys[start]] == undefined) {
      console.warn("Object valid till", keys.slice(0,start),keys[start],"undefined");
      return false;
    } else {
      if (start + 1 >= keys.length) {
        return data[keys[start]];
      }
      return this.isAccessible(data[keys[start]], keys, start + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

**function call in code**

Suppose we have a Object `obj` keys of which can vary and we want to check
if `obj.key1.key2` is accessible or not then function call will be as follows:

```
isAccessible(Object,["key1","key2"])
```