# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to filter a column of a ngx-table I follow the the example but it keeps giving that error  "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

here's the template part

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Nom" class="name">
  <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
    {{value}}
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

and the function attached to it

```
updateFilter(event) {
const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

// filter the data
const temp = this.temp.filter(function(d) {
  return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
});

// update the rows
this.rows = temp;
// Whenever the filter changes, always go back to the first page
this.table.offset = 0;}
```

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript "cannot read property "bar" of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004617/javascript-cannot-read-property-bar-of-undefined)

Comment: @DeborahK, you're right. I misunderstood the explanation of _safe navigator operator_. Here it is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238144/typescript-the-safe-navigation-operator-or-and-null-property-paths) and as explained there, there is still an [open issue about it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16). Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the the items being filtered through do not all contain a value 'name' within them. Try `console.log(d)` before your return within that function to verify you are receiving the data you expect.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your `name` property must be undefined in some cases. This could be that it is not the correct property name (is it `lastName` instead of `name`?) or that for some objects in the `temp` array that the value is undefined. In either case, you can check for a null first before returning the value.

```
if (d.name) {
  return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
} else {
  return null;
}
```