# Why is currentUser.uid undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add information to the document of the user currently logged in.

I have the following code snippet of code in my component -

```
console.log("user", auth.currentUser?.uid);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(auth.currentUser?.uid)
        .collection("cart")
        .doc(productId)
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => setProduct(snapshot.data()));
    }
  }, []);
```

Here,

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
```

The console log actually gives me the uid of the user but the hook below produces an errror -

**FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined**

I have used the same approach in another component to add data and it works fine.

Why does this happen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`auth.currentUser` is going to be null if there is no user signed in at the moment it was accessed.  Your code is blindly ignoring this possibility by using the `?` operator to "safely" access its properties anyway.  When you use `?`, if the prior expression is "falsy", the entire expression becomes undefined.  Your code should instead check for null before assuming there is an object to use.

```
const currentUser = auth.currentUser
if (currentUser) {
    const uid = currentUser.uid;
}
else {
    // what do you want to do if there is no one signed in?
}
```

If you need to wait until a user is actually signed in, you should use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to get a callback that tells you when the user object is available.

See also: [Typescript the safe navigation operator ( ?. ) or (!.) and null property paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238144/typescript-the-safe-navigation-operator-or-and-null-property-paths)