# core.js:5980 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined (angular)

Tags: angular, model, string-interpolation, angular-event-emitter

I can't generate card with information in angular

my model:

```
export class order {
    Name!: string
    Surname!: string
    Email!: string
    Type!: string
    Description!: string

    constructor(name: string, surname: string, email: string, type: string, desc: string) {
        this.Name = name,
            this.Surname = surname,
            this.Email = email,
            this.Type = type,
            this.Description = desc
    }
}
```

card component typescript:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { order } from 'src/app/shared models/order.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-card',
  templateUrl: './contact-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-card.component.css']
})
export class ContactCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  item!: order;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

card component html:

```
<div class="card">
    <h3>{{item.Name}} {{item.Surname}}</h3>
    <div class="flex">
        <p>{{item.Email}}</p>
        <p>{{item.Type}}</p>
    </div>
    <p>{{item.Description}}</p>
</div>
```

It says that the error is on my html when I interpolate string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the value of `item`. It is probably `null` or `undefined` and that's why this error occurs. In order to avoid this error, please try the following:

```
<div class="card">
    <h3>{{item?.Name}} {{item?.Surname}}</h3>
    <div class="flex">
        <p>{{item?.Email}}</p>
        <p>{{item?.Type}}</p>
    </div>
    <p>{{item?.Description}}</p>
</div>
```

Read [Safe navigation operator (?.) or (!.) and null property paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238144/safe-navigation-operator-or-and-null-property-paths) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific need to use a class for `order`? Classes need to be instantiated. If it doesn't contain methods and if there isn't explicit need, I'd recommend you to use TS [Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) instead. It allows for type checking without the "bloat" that comes with class.

```js
export interface order {
    Name!: string;
    Surname!: string;
    Email!: string;
    Type!: string;
    Description!: string;
}
```

You could then use safe-navigation operator `?.` in Angular template to avoid potential `undefined` errors. It checks if the object is defined before trying to access it's properties.

```html
<div class="card">
    <h3>{{item?.Name}} {{item?.Surname}}</h3>
    <div class="flex">
        <p>{{item?.Email}}</p>
        <p>{{item?.Type}}</p>
    </div>
    <p>{{item?.Description}}</p>
</div>
```