# What is ?. in Angular / Type Script

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to the front end development and I am self learning Angular (11.2.10). I came across this piece of in a sample project in the html template written by someone else and is used at bunch of places:

```
<div #itemsList [currentItemId]="item?.id"></div>
```

I am wondering for what `?.` is used for here? I want to learn more about it. Even I am not sure if it is part of TS or Angular?

What should I search for to learn about this expression in the official documentation of Angular/TS?

May be I have not covered that topic yet in my learning yet. Any information in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Based on answers by polyglot and liyaxing I found what I looking for - [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Also, similar question was asked here too

[Safe navigation operator (?.) or (!.) and null property paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238144/safe-navigation-operator-or-and-null-property-paths)

But since I didn't know what I was looking for, I wish not to delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a kind of ternary operator in Typescript such that if object `item` exists and contains `id` property, then `item.id` is picked up; otherwise, `null` is picked up. It's used when the object is nullable. Therefore your code is identical to the following:

`<div #itemsList [currentItemId]="item? item.id : null"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

The question mark is used to mark the TypeScript variable as optional.
This is to avoid `TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of null` if the variable `item` is `null`. So in the case that `item` is `null` or `undefined`, "`item?.id`" will return `undefined` instead of throwing an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: so what should I "google" for to learn more about it? As I mentioned in the original question I want to learn it all. - `Type Script Optional` ?

Comment: You can search for "Type Script Optional Parameters". You can find resources like https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters

Comment: This answer isn't quite correct in this context. `?` does mark a property as optional, but that's not what's happening here. Here, you are accessing a property that's already optional, and doing it in a `null`ish-safe way.

Comment: It's optional chaining
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html