# There is a json data and how to bind json field using dot path in angular 12 html?

Tags: angular, typescript

There is a json data and how to bind json field using dot path in angular 12 html?

Example:

```
//Angular
data: any = { name: 'x1', address: { city: 'xyz' } };
field: any = 'address.city';

//Html
<input [(ngModel)]="data[field]"/> //output: undefined
```

How to bind and display city using json dot path?

I don't want as

```
<input [(ngModel)]="data.address.city"/>
<input [(ngModel)]="data['address']['city']"/>
```

Comment: (FYI [tag:angular] != [tag:angularjs] )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safe navigation operator (?.) or (!.) and null property paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238144/safe-navigation-operator-or-and-null-property-paths)

Comment: no, this is not answered for my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use safe navigation operator (?) to display the value of city in html.

Such as:

<input [(ngModel)]="data?.address?.city"/>

Comment: no, object is not static one. In my case, object & field will be dynamic one. Example: other one. data: any = { name: 'x1', area: { town: 'abc' } };
field: any = 'area.town';

Comment: You can go through this article. https://dev.to/rramname/read-properties-of-json-object-and-its-values-dynamically-in-angular-javascript-3db2

Comment: no, it is an article for simple object example like { "name": "x1", "mobile": "1234"}. My case is different