# What exactly is the difference between ?. and !. in Angular?

Tags: angular

I've got the next line of code in my html template file:

```
    <span *ngIf="!signupForm.get('email')!.valid && signupForm.get('email')?.touched">
```

The 1st condition of the if has **!.** and the 2nd condition has **?.**    .

Both works just fine and when I don't use ? or ! it gives me the error: **Object is possibly 'null'**.

So does it really matter which one I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safe navigation operator (?.) or (!.) and null property paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238144/safe-navigation-operator-or-and-null-property-paths)

Answer (score 2):

`!.` is TypeScript's [null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-), which asserts that the programmer knows the value to be not null, and asks typescript to believe the programmer. Should the value be null anyway, you'll get an exception.

`?.` is EcmaScript's [optional chaining](https://javascript.info/optional-chaining#optional-chaining), which will access the property if the base is defined, or return undefined otherwise.

Comment: So does it matter which one I use in the given example?

Comment: Of course it matter! if you have
    *let yourUser: User = null;*
if you call
    *yourUser!.name //throw error*
instead
    *youUser?.name //undefined*