# Does TypeScript have a Null-conditional operator

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Is there any operator like ?. in TypeScript that can check if the variable is null or not defined like Kotlin? Like

```
person?.getName()?.firstName ?: "None"
```

Comment: Not to my knowledge, there's just a operator which tells the compiler that a value won't be `null`: (`person!.getName()`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Typescript support the ?. operator? (And, what's it called?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260732/does-typescript-support-the-operator-and-whats-it-called)

Comment: Yes. But I think this operator is just for compiler but does nothing to check. If the person is null in runtime, I suppose it will cause an error. Is is right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. When I search ?. in typescript, stackoverflow did not give that. Sorry for the duplication.

Comment: In HTML It is allowed but not in TS

Comment: This is now available as of TS 3.7, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60594782/618441, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, as of now safe navigation operatior is still not implemented in Typescript:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16

However according to the latest standardization meeting notes it has been proposed, so maybe v3 :)

https://github.com/tc39/agendas/blob/master/2017/07.md

Comment: Thank you. I have looked through the handbook but did not find anything. I think this operator is useful and beautiful that eliminate a lot of shit code. Do you have any idea whether this operator is intended to be included in ES standards in the future?

Comment: As a side note typescript does have the ``?`` operator but does not do that.

Comment: For anyone looking, here is the [related javascript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).

Comment: _so maybe v3_ v3 is out, maybe this answer needs to be updated (even if it is just to say it was not accepted if that is the case

Comment: I'm using Typescript v3.7.2 but still not found this feature. could someone help please?

Comment: it is now possible see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60594782/224410)

Comment: been possible since 3.7.x version somewhere, and as of ES2020, also just available in javascript.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, as of Typescript 3.7 you can now do this via [optional-chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

```
person?.getName()?.firstName
```

gets transpiled to

```
let firstName = person === null || person === void 0 ? void 0 : (_person$getName = person.getName()) === null || _person$getName === void 0 ? void 0 : _person$getName.firstName;
```

Note the check for null. This will work as expected if for example person is defined as

```
let person:any = null; //no runtime TypeError when calling person?.getName()
```

However if person is defined as

```
let person:any = {};//Uncaught TypeError: person.getName is not a function
```

See also this [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260732/does-typescript-support-the-operator-and-whats-it-called)

Comment: Similarly, [nullish coalescing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) also exists as of TS 3.7: `let x = foo ?? bar();`

Answer (score 8):

I've encountered the same situation, and the following worked for me.

First, I defined a separate class with a property that can be `null`:

```
export class Foo {
    id: number; //this can be null
}
```

Then in my main class I set a property `foo` to this new type:

```
foo: Foo
```

After that, I was able to use it like this:

```
var fooId = (this.foo || ({} as Foo)).id;
```

This is the closest I could get to have a null propagation in a current version of TypeScript.

Answer (score 4):

The actual good answer is in [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618441/andreashassing)' comment. Your example would be implemented as below from Typescript 3.7 onwards :

```
person?.getName()?.firstName ?? "None"
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is related to javascript null safety [discussion](https://github.com/gisenberg/proposal-nullary-coalescing) that is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript). I guess they want it to be supported on javascript before they will get to typescript.

Answer (score 3):

I used this in my code to check for null

```
this.firstname = (this.firstname != null) ? this.firstname : this.firstname;
```

This could do till v3 is out

Answer (score 2):

Not only is it supported in typescript (since version 3.7.2).
It is also supported in javascript now (since ES2020).

- In practice that means you can use it in frameworks like Angular
  ([since v9 which supports typescript 3.7](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3)).
- But especially now that **it is in the ES2020 spec**, we will be seeing it
  everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

This will set `item` to `null` if there is no e-mail:

```
let item = user?.email;
```