# Getting errors because it tries to render before I initialize my variables?

Tags: angular

I try to render a profile webpage using Angular.
Here is my profile component:

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUser : User;
  userVisited : User;

  constructor(public _userService:UserService, private  router:Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if(this.currentUser == null){
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this._userService.getUser(params['userId']).subscribe(res => {
        console.log (res);
        if(res.success){
          this.userVisited = res.user;
          console.log(this.userVisited.firstName);
        }
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Now, I try to render `<h1>{{userVisited.firstName}} {{userVisited.lastName}}</h1>`. But it gives me at first in the console errors :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
```

Then, it still renders the right `firstName` and `lastName`because it seems those errors are printed before it went through the Init function.

Any ideas on how to avoid those errors?

Comment: You can display a spinner during the loading of the data and use the if/else in angular template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an *ngIf in h1 tag to render data after userVisited has data

```
<h1 *ngIf="userVisited">{{userVisited.firstName}} {{userVisited.lastName}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your HTML add `?` operator on variables that are loading, this way:

```
<h1>{{userVisited?.firstName}} {{userVisited?.lastName}}</h1>
```

So it won't try to access nested properties until `userVisited` has a value.

Comment: Super nice, Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not very fan of this solution because the ? means: it's optional whereas userVisited is not an optional value. Here it's just not defined yet

Comment: The ? means: if userVisited has a value, then try to access firstName and lastName. It is not an optional value, it says that that variable could be null, and this is the case, until the async call completes

Comment: @GianlucaParis, ?. it's an existential operator (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260732/does-typescript-support-the-operator-and-whats-it-called), we have both right but you're more right than me :)