# Object is possibly null. TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, eslint

How to fix ESLint error: "Object is possibly null"?
In my code I'm checking null, but anyway have error

```
if (controlInput !== null) {
  if (controlInput.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g).length !== 0) {
    return 'some message'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is not about `controlInput` but about the value returned by [`controlInput.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value).

It is an `Array` if the value of `controlInput` matches the regular expression or `null` if it doesn't match.

The common solution is to extract the value returned by `controlInput.match()` into a variable then use it only if it is not `null`.

```js
if (controlInput !== null) {
  const matches = controlInput.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g);
  if (matches && matches.length) {
    return 'some message';
  }
}
```

But if you don't care about the matching substrings but only if the string matches a regex you can check directly the value returned by `controInput.match()`:

```js
if (controlInput !== null && controlInput.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g)) {
  return 'some message';
}
```

Or, even better, use [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). It is faster.

```js
if (controlInput !== null && /[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/.test(controlInput)) {
  return 'some message';
}
```

### Some thoughts about the regex

Apparently you want to check if the value of `controlInput` contains some special characters.

In `regexp`, the expression `[...]` is called ["character set"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) and it matches one character from the list of characters specified between the square brackets.

Most characters represent themselves in a character set. However, there are two characters that are special in a character set. One of them is `^` but only if it is the first character in the character set (immediately after `[`). It negates the meaning of the character set.

The other special character is `-`, when it is not the first or the last character in the character set. `[a-z]` does not mean "one of `a`, `-` or `z`" but "any character between and including `a` and `z`", i.e. any lowercase letter.

The character class in your regular expression contains the fragment `"-=` that in a character set matches all characters between and including `"` and `=` in the [ASCII code](https://www.ascii-code.com). This subset includes `.`, `,`, `;` and other characters you already included in the character set.

This is why I think your intention was not to include all characters between `"` and `=` but only the characters `"`, `-` and `=`.

In order to get the expected behaviour (`-` to represent itself) move `-` at the beginning or at the end of the set.

```js
if (controlInput !== null && /[-$;.,'"=!@#$%^&*()]/.test(controlInput)) {
  return 'some message';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `match()` method has a return type of `RegExpMatchArray | null`. So the return value of `match()` may be `null`, which is when the regex does not match the string. And `null.length` will raise an error at runtime.

You can fix this by just not checking the length. The `match()` method will either return `null` if it does not match or and array with at least one string if it does match. That means you can use the result of `match()` directly in your conditional:

```
if (controlInput.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g)) {
  return 'some message'
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=6&ssc=6&pln=4&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIxCBAZykISgCc4AbASTAAcQoAuRUymMAc0QB9EYEDRqIAvIgBEUAKalufAIwAmAMxT8iGMERoiYKrQbMyAQnGThorHgIEdeg0fpMWAOgC2AQygQAFmgA9ADaACQA3O4ANADkUgC04mYAAgDEYQCkAHoAZABUmAC6QTwYtlr2iJSyUCCUSLHEcJ6yiK3ExN48srGViAC+WkMENXUNiE0tbXBQ-rKU7fJdPX0DQA)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of typescript you are using, you can use the optional chaining operator (see accepted answer [Does Typescript support the ?. operator? (And, what's it called?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260732/does-typescript-support-the-operator-and-whats-it-called))

```
if (controlInput?.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g).length !== 0) {
    return 'some message' 
  }
```

Adding the error message and location of error would be helpful, as I am guessing to where the issue is presenting.

Also, if you are using an older version of typescript, you could always have one if check like...

```
if (controlInput
    && controlInput.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g).length !== 0
) {
  return 'some message' 
}
```

Comment: This one doesn't work. I have no clue what`s wrong here

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is by using [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) (the `?` operator):

```
if(controlInput?.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g)?.length !== 0) {
  return 'some message'
}
```

This achieves the same effect as writing:

```
if (controlInput !== null) {
  const matches = controlInput.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g)

  if (matches && matches.length !== 0) {
    return 'some message'
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I have an error on this line `controlInput.match(/[$;.,'"-=!@#$%^&*()]/g).length !== 0`

Comment: I rewrote the second code block, can you try that out?