# Is only one '?' property enough in my case with TypeScript Optional chaining

Tags: reactjs, typescript, optional-chaining

In my React and TypeScript (version `"^3.9.9"`) app I am mapping over some items to render the list/teasers:

```
    {data?.getItems.items
      .map((teaser) => (
        <Teaser
          key={teaser.id}
          title={teaser.extraData?.title || video.title}
          label={teaser.extraData?.label}
        />
      ))}
```

`extraData` object can be null queried with Graphql from api. I am using Typescripts [Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html).

It's enough to prevent my app from breaking to add `teaser.extraData?.title`.

But what is the difference between `teaser?.extraData?.title` and `teaser.extraData?.title` and what should I use to be safe?

Comment: "*But what is the difference between teaser?.extraData?.title and teaser.extraData?.title and what should I use to be safe?*" the first one will work if `teaser` is undefined or null. The second assumes that will never be the case. So, it depends - *can* `teaser` be undefined or null? If yes, use optional chaining on it. Otherwise it's technically superfluous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Typescript support the ?. operator? (And, what's it called?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260732/does-typescript-support-the-operator-and-whats-it-called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what is the difference between `teaser?.extraData?.title` and `teaser.extraData?.title` and what should I use to be safe?

The first one will evaluate to `undefined` without error if `teaser`, itself, is `null` or `undefined` (collectively: "nullish"). The second will throw an error in that case, because you've chained (non-optionally) from `teaser`.

The way optional chaining works, the entire property access operation is short-circuited (resulting in `undefined`) at the point of the optional chain **if** the thing just before the optional chain is `null` or `undefined`.

So in your example, apparently `teaser` is always non-nullish, but `teaser.extraData` is sometimes nullish. So you only need optional chaining after `teaser.extraData`, not `teaser`, in this specific case.

---

Side note: [Optional chaining](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) is part of JavaScript now, it was added to the ES2020 specification after having been natively implemented by all major engines. It's not just TypeScript (anymore).